# Получить текущую директоию с помощью js

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как можно получить текущую директорию файла с помощью js? Нашел только путь к файлу `window.location.href`.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript не работает с файловой системой из-за политики безопасности. Да и то, что вы получаете с помощью `window.location.href`, является всего лишь адресом страницы, просто локально запущенной (с хостингом такое не прокатит).

Comment: а мне и не нужно с хостингом, мне надо примерно тоже только без конечного файла

Comment: тогда только остается парсить: `window.location.href.replace( /[^\/]+$/g, '' )`

Answer (score 0):

JS очень ревностно защищает файловую систему, по сути в нём вообще нет интерфейсов к драйверам ФС.
Даже вроде бы выбранный файл через `<input type='file' />`, у которого виден путь, в JS представляется так: `C:\fakepath\fileName`, т.е. путь скрыт.
Проделать простейшие операции, в принципе, можно, новые стандарты более лояльны, но это страшный геморрой, лучше не надо.

Что такое "текущая директория"?
Файл хранится на сервере, на клиенте он в кэше, зачем тебе это?